# I am a software engineer, should I include my Math.SE in my LinkedIn profile?

Tags: software-industry, resume, job-search, linkedin

I am a software engineer and I have been working on my LinkedIn profile.

I have added a link to my software blog to my profile and I thought about adding my [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21335/belgi) profile as well as I have been active there in the past both asking and answering questions. I know that many requiters and companies consider it an advantage to have an active stackoverflow user that gives answers - but unfortunately I haven't been active there at all.

I fear that this would make me look as more math-theory oriented and not as a strong candidate for a software engineering position. On the other side I have spent many hours trying to help people and and math is related to computer science..

What should I do in this case ?

Comment: Having maths skills are a top quality for a software engineer.  By all means showcase it!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm a senior guy who is a current reviewer of technical resumes for my company; In my opinion, anything like SE participation or Github/Gitlab projects that helps me to get a better idea of what you do and who you are is very welcome.

Comment: Good point.  I went to an interview a few months back where they had a virtual machine fired up with the intent that I might want to pull up something in Github to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest that it would not hurt. It makes logical sense, as one has to be on the internet to see your Linked In profile and it's just a simple click to see the SE profile.

Linked In is also perhaps a little less formal than a resume, in which I would not put the profile link.

Answer (score 1):

Its up to you on if you want to include your SE rating on your LinkedIn, in my opinion it would be great to see an active member despite the community that you are mainly involved in. For more info on how to do this effectively I would check out [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121355/how-can-i-insert-my-stack-overflow-rating-into-linkedin).

Another thing you could do instead is to include a link to your SE on your blog for possible employers to see if they visit there.